# memtest86+ cannot boot via systemd-boot EFI

Tags: uefi, systemd-boot, memtest

Recently has been released version 6 of Memtest86+ which finally introduce UEFI support.

Now, I use `systemd-boot` as boot manager, so I'd like to launch memtest86+ directly at boot.
I set up a configuration file `/boot/loader/entries/memtest.conf` as described here **[1]**:

```
title     Memory Tester (memtest86+)
efi       /memtest86+/memtest.efi
```

With no luck! It results in a blank screen.
**Help me: What I do wrong?**

I am on Arch Linux w/ `memtest86+-efi` **[2]** 6.00-2

**UPDATE1:** reported the issue in Arch Linux bug tracker **[3]**

---

**[1]** https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-boot#EFI_Shells_or_other_EFI_applications
**[2]** https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/memtest86+-efi/
**[3]** https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/76390

Comment: What does `ls /boot/efi` show? I'm betting that your entry should be `efi   /EFI/memtest+86/memtest.efi`.

Comment: @ajgringo619 nothing at least not the implicated `memtest.efi` since it is installed under `/boot/memtest86+/memtest.efi`

Comment: I've only used `memtest86-efi`, so if the EFI files are in the right place, then I've got no idea why you're getting a blank screen. Maybe give the other one a shot.

Comment: I opened a bug report in Arch Linux bug tracker https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/76390

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It was an issue](https://github.com/memtest86plus/memtest86plus/issues/202)

Now solved upstream. Starting with version 6.10 you can launch `memtest86+` from `systemd-boot` out-of-the-box.